# PHP SimpleXML error update xml file

Tags: php, html, simplexml

So heres my problem! I am using simplexml in my website as a substitute for MySQL because I'm using a mobile, its working fine with the addChild request but when it submits it either overrides the original xml file or well il explain it with code xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<video><title>title 22</title></video>
```

Php file:

```
<?php
$file = 'database.xml';
$title = $_POST['1'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$xmlne = $xml->videos;
$d = "<video></video>";
 $newvid = new SimpleXMLElement($d);
$newvid->addChild('title' , $title);
$newvid->asXML($file);
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" value="title" name="1">
<input type="submit" value="post"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Say if i put title 23 into the form it overrides <title> to 23

Comment: _"il explain it with code xml file"_: Better explain it with words, _then_ show the code to reproduce it. I don't really understand _"it either overrides the original xml"_ and I don't want to have to execute it in my brain _just in order to understand the question_!

Comment: The data saves but i want it to increment so it adds a new element under the others

Comment: It's recommended to edit your question to include missing information rather than only mentioning it in comments.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that this line creates a new XML document, completely separate from the original file:

```
$newvid = new SimpleXMLElement($d);
```

You are then adding an element to your new document, and saving out to the original file name, losing the original file.

What you actually want to do is add a new Video element to the existing document which you loaded as `$xml` and then traversed to find `$xmlne`:

```
$newvid = $xmlne->addChild('video');
```