# trying to edit xml file using php simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, saving-data

so I am trying to edit an xml file using php's simplexml extension but I am getting some problems and its 
when I tried

```
  $settings = simplexml_load_file("settings.xml");
  ....
  if(isset($aInformation['cName'])) 
  {
     $settings->general->communityname = $aInformation['cName'];
     $settings->asXML();
  }
```

but I failed with the saving step...

```
  $settings = simplexml_load_file("settings.xml");
  $xmlconfigs = new SimpleXMLElement($settings); 
  ....
  if(isset($aInformation['cName'])) 
  {
     $settings->general->communityname = $aInformation['cName'];
     $xmlconfigs->asXML();
  }
```

but I failed too with the error

```
  String couldn't be parsed to XML...
```

and I had tried searching on those posts before but they are the same as my failed example codes something [edit XML with simpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092172/edit-xml-with-simplexml) and [PHP SimpleXML error update xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683029/php-simplexml-error-update-xml-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second one is not possible as `SimpleXMLElement` can only take a well-formed XML string or the path or URL to an XML document. But you are passing an object of class `SimpleXMLElement` returned by `simplexml_load_file`. That is the reason it was throwing error `String couldn't be parsed to XML...`

In first one the [`asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method accepts an optional filename as parameter that will save the current structure as XML to a file.

> If the filename isn't specified, this function returns a string on
>   success and `FALSE` on error. If the parameter is specified, it
>   returns `TRUE` if the file was written successfully and `FALSE`
>   otherwise.

So once you have updated your XML with the hints, just save it back to file.

```
$settings = simplexml_load_file("settings.xml");
....
if(isset($aInformation['cName'])) 
 {
   $settings->general->communityname = $aInformation['cName'];
   // Saving the whole modified XML to a new filename
   $settings->asXml('updated_settings.xml');
   // Save only the modified node
   $settings->general->communityname->asXml('settings.xml');
 }
```

Comment: Edit: after some tests again i used `$settings->asXml('settings.xml');` only so it saves the whole settings xml file's content :D thanks so much sir and it works great